# Extract sentence and value from string in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Person.ID = c(123L, 234L),
  Date = c("10/10/09", "11/11/03"),
  Text = c(
    "Here are some random words that I do not want. The person was allowed to cool to a core body temperature of 16.5 degrees centigrade. Here are some other random words I do not want.",
    "Here are some random words that I do not want. A cooling mechanism was applied to cool the patient to a core body temperature of 19.1 degrees centigrade. Here are some other random words I do not want."
  )
)
```

For each person, I would like to extract the sentence that mentions their body temperature (and get rid of the unwanted words). I would also like a separate column that ONLY mentions the temperature. The desired output should look like:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Person.ID = c(123L, 234L),
  Date = c("10/10/09", "11/11/03"),
  Text = c(
    "The person was allowed to cool to a core body temperature of 16.5 degrees centigrade.",
    "A cooling mechanism was applied to cool the patient to a core body temperature of 19.1 degrees centigrade. "
  ),
  Value = c(16.5, 19.1)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 separate_longer_delim(Text, delim = regex("(?<=\\.)\\s+")) %>% 
 filter(str_detect(Text, "temperature")) %>% 
 mutate(Value = as.numeric(str_extract(Text, "\\d+\\.?\\d+?")))
```

-output

```
 Person.ID     Date
1       123 10/10/09
2       234 11/11/03
                                                                                                        Text Value
1                      The person was allowed to cool to a core body temperature of 16.5 degrees centigrade.  16.5
2 A cooling mechanism was applied to cool the patient to a core body temperature of 19.1 degrees centigrade.  19.1
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach would be to split the string into sentences then use `sapply` with `grep`:

```
ll <- strsplit(df$Text, "(?<=[[:punct:]])\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)

df[, "Text"] <- sapply(seq_along(ll), 
                       function(x) ll[[x]][grep("temperature", ll[[x]])])

df[, "value"] <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+\\.?\\D+?", "", df$Text))

# Person.ID     Date                                                                                                       Text value
# 1       123 10/10/09                      The person was allowed to cool to a core body temperature of 16.5 degrees centigrade.  16.5
# 2       234 11/11/03 A cooling mechanism was applied to cool the patient to a core body temperature of 19.1 degrees centigrade.  19.1
```